# Bootstrap 4 - Child automatically aligns center (vertically) when parent height is longer than child

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was using bootstrap 4 when I found this behaviour unexpected:

https://jsfiddle.net/hzse8gfd/1/

In my fiddle, I have a sidebar which is stretched to screen's maximum height.I then have a 50px logo sitting on top of the sidebar, and a div that holds the rest of the sidebar content.

What I realised is that the content gets vertically pushed down/align center of the parent height, when I am expecting it stick to the top, just like the logo segment. Just curious why is the behavior as such.

I'm using bootstrap 4

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="row">
    <div class="col-12 logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 sidebar-content">
        <div class="row">
            <ul id="sidebar-results">
                <li>Result 1</li>
                <li>Result 2</li>
                <li>Result 3</li>
                <li>Result 4</li>
                <li>Result 5</li>
                <li>Result 6</li>
                <li>Result 7</li>
                <li>Result 8</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
}

#sidebar{
  height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it's because you use `.col-12` twice in a single `.row`, while total amount of columns should add up to `12` - your case: `24`.

```css
.logo{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
}

#sidebar{
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="sidebar">
  <!-- LOGO ROW -->
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 logo"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- RESULTS ROW -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 sidebar-content">
        <ul id="sidebar-results">
          <li>Result 1</li>
          <li>Result 2</li>
          <li>Result 3</li>
          <li>Result 4</li>
          <li>Result 5</li>
          <li>Result 6</li>
          <li>Result 7</li>
          <li>Result 8</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: cool. Didnt know that bootstrap don't allow a "row" to have more than 12 columns